# How to inherit a view in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a view in Ember.js that looks like:

```
MyApp.LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'login',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $("body").addClass("light-bg");
    $("footer").css("display", "none");
    $("input[name=email]").focus();
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    $("body").removeClass("light-bg");
    $("footer").css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

I need another view which is exactly the same, except it is called `ForgotPassword`, thus the only difference is the `templateName`.

Is there a way in Ember.js, I can say `ForgotPassword` inherits `Login`, and then just set templateName to `forgotPassword`?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, within your `didInsertElement`/`willDestroyElement`, you should only be directly manipulating DOM elements that this this view's element or descendants, and when you do, use `this.$()`. e.g. `this.$('input[name=email]')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply extend from the view you just created:

```
MyApp.YourOtherView = MyApp.LoginView.extend({
   // whatever you do here will be applied to `YourOtherView` only.. so
   templateName: 'other/template'
});
```